# Change color scheme excel programmatically

Tags: .net, vsto, excel-2007, excel-2010

I develop an excel add-in and I need to implement color picker dialog with some set of user-defined colors. 
I figured out that I can create a new color theme using the dialog "Page Layout" -> "Themes" -> "Colors" -> "Customize Colors...".
But still, I can't find the way how can I change theme colors programmatically.

Maybe, there is no way.

Please, help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
 Globals.ThisWorkbook.ApplyTheme("theme.thmx")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MICROSOFT.OFFICE.TOOLS.EXCEL.WORKBOOKBASE.APPLYTHEME);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true

Comment: Well, I think this is what I need. I can create theme by myself and then include in into the add-in installer. Thank you!